# Replication issues on the subscriber side

Tags: sql-server, replication

So here is my situation,  an old admin who moved off to some better place had setup replication.   Come that special day when the admins account was disabled, replication stopped working.   No problem, we generated the scripts.  Disabled everything and recreated replication.  It all looks to be working correctly, with the performance status of "Excellent"

Now a few weeks passed and I realize none of the tables have updated on the subscribers.

Now I tried to re-initialize the But I see things stuck with this error

> The initial snapshot for publication X is not yet available."

Been like that for the last hour.

Reading on, some people suggest to troubleshoot this. I am down for that,  anyone have any pointers as to what I can look at?

Another suggestion was to look for a corrupted snapshot.  I am very interested how to identify a bad snapshot and how to fix it. What are the steps for that?

Here are some things I have completed. 
[] Attempted to Resync

Note - before re-syncing I did generated a fresh snapshot using these instructions:

1. Open Distribution Server
2. Expand Replication, expand Local Publications.
3. Right click the publication and select View Snapshot agent status.
4. Click start and watch the snapshot be generated.

   - The snapshot finished quickly
   - The results,  well things still were not syncing.

Ok another suggestion was to delete the subscription on the subscriber.  Me being scared, tested this theory.  Deleted the subscription on a test setup.  Resynced, and the subscription was recreated and had new valid entries.

Now I tried that in production,  well I am stuck with the state of:

> The initial snapshot for publication X is not yet available.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just create another snapshot, and it will work.

Comment: Aside from any service accounts not having access to the bcp files, sometimes the windows shared directory becomes corrupted. But that is just a few issues that can occur. Sometimes it also is the subscriber/distributor that is at fault